# ページ内のすべてのリンクについて、クリックを無効化したい

Tags: google-chrome

クリック無効化と言うと誤解釈を生むかも知れませんが、Websiteの形はそのままにマウスオーバー辞書など自由に使いたいと考えています。

リンクの展開を無効にするChromeアプリはないでしょうか。

1. クリックを無効化できる
2. ダブルクリックでテキストを反転などはしたい
3. ページの見た目はそのままで閲覧したい

既存のChromeの機能でできたりするものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そんなニッチな要望には、[LinkSuppressor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linksuppressor-make-any-l/jffdmjmhkinopagcjgfjjfoagglhnhff?hl=ja) をどうぞ。

ページ上の全てのリンクを、一括してテキスト化してしまうエクステンションは結構ありますが、これは `A` タグの上でマウスのボタンを押した瞬間だけリンク解除し、すぐに戻すという小さなハックです。ダブルクリック選択はちょっと動作が微妙かな。[ソース](https://github.com/hyamamoto/linksuppressor)は公開しています。動作などがわからないところがあれば、スタック・オーバーフローで質問や要望をされれば、きっとすぐ対応されるはずです。

*補足:*

Firefox は、昔から <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd>でリンクテキストを選択できるようになっています。 すでに最近の Chrome に同機能があるかもしれません。